# Python subprocess, Popen, Communicate from a thread

Tags: python, subprocess, python-multithreading

Using subprocess module to run a command, and communicate method to pass stdin input to the command. This works fine when running standalone, not as a thread:

```
cmd = ["/usr/bin/nc", "-w0", "-u", hostname, port]

while count <= interval:
    j = 0
    while j < burst:
        p1 = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate(json.dumps(data))
        time.sleep(0.01)
        j = j + 1
    count = count+1
    time.sleep(1)
```

However, when trying to run the code as a thread, I keep getting a OSError: [Errno 32] Broken Pipe when the shell command is executed.

I suspect the problem is trying to access STDIN and STDOUT by different threads simultaneously? Any way to make this thread safe?

I am using the thread module as follows:

```
import thread
t = thread.start_new_thread( senddata, (mac, interval)
```

Comment: 1. use `threading` module instead of `thread`. 2. Could you create [a complete minimal code example](http://sscce.org/) that shows your problem and post the full traceback that it produces

Comment: you could use `socket` module instead of running `nc`.

Comment: add stderr=subprocess.PIPE to the mix.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian i tried `threading` with same behavior. I ended up using `socket` per your suggestion instead. thanks

Comment: @tdelaney adding stderr to the `Popen` didn't change the behavior. still getting the same error in the communicate call.

Comment: Using Popen  will be buggy in multi-threaded enviroment